# 100v audio source volume control / distribution

Tags: audio, solid-state-relay

I have an audio signal from a class-d  100V and 500W. amplifier.

I want to distribute this to 16 different sets of speakers and control the volume of each set individually. I am unable to find any solution for 100V.

If volume control isn't possible I would like to be able to switch ON/OFF.Relays are one of a solution but that will be taking a lot of board space ,which is limited for my application. I was interested in [this Chip](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/rdha701fp10a8ck.pdf), but the availability is an issue and I cant find it.

Can someone please help me to find any solution for volume control, or finding me an alternate IC or any other solution.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar IC. Did you find anything?

Comment: Can you post a link to the amplifiers' manufacturer, data sheets or specifications, please?

Comment: @EMFields Its a 100A 500W class-D Amplifier. http://csinewave.com/up500

Answer (score 1):

This is traditionally done with a [transformer](http://uk.farnell.com/oep-oxford-electrical-products/d29a100/transformer-100v-line-univers/dp/1172434?ost=100V%20audio%20transformers) for each speaker. Volume adjustment is by selecting a tap on the secondary to deliver the required power to the speaker; as such, you get a choice of maybe 6 volume levels, (and off!) which you could select with a [rotary switch](http://uk.farnell.com/lorlin/ck1025/switch-2pole-6-pos-5a-125v/dp/1123688) at the speaker.

Comment: I would like to control the volume or switch ON/OFF using a micro-controller or raspberry pi via an app .

Comment: @dmsherazi: Since it significantly changes the scope of your question, you should edit your question to include that requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure solid state relays would work to switch transformer taps because Ron is going to be high relative to the speaker resistance and Ron flatness (which is not something you usually see in an SSR datasheet because it's an AC characteristic) will introduce significant distortion. So I think you would have to use regular relays.

Comment: @ioplex Should i be looking for the DC 100V rating or AC 100V rating for a relay for this purpose! I am noob as far as audio and amplifiers are considered.

will this one be OK? http://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5sb.pdf .

Would Opening one of the two wires going to speaker, be enough , or do I need to Open both the wires?

Comment: That relay should be fine. If you are switching after the transformer, switching a single pole is adequate. You can either preselect a tap for the best volume, or use several relays to choose volume levels.

Answer (score -1):

Volume control is usually performed *before* the power amplification stage.  To drive multiple speakers with their own volume settings you would usually use a separate power amplifier for each set of speakers, each with its own volume control.

Implementing volume control after the power amplification stage is a tricky business since you have to work within the tight constraints of the impedance of the speaker system, and as you have found, often at higher voltages and currents.

Comment: if I skip volume control, what would you suggest for switching on/off of different sets of speakers? 

any alternatives to this http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/rdha701fp10a8ck.pdf

Comment: Switching speakers on and off is itself not an easy task.  The amplifier expects a certain load impedance. You have to try and match that load impedance with your speakers. By adding and removing extra speakers you are changing that impedance, and the amplifier may well have a fit.  Some won't even start working if you have the wrong impedance.

Comment: It won't be done quite often or even done only when the amplifier is OFF.I want to be able to control the sections of the building where the audio should be played.

Comment: It's not a question of frequency, or if the amplifier is on or off - it's a question of getting the impedance right.  You could arrange it so that certain combinations of speakers can be on at once, where those combinations equal the right impedance.

Comment: OK. I got the point. But I am still in need of a solution to switch 100V signal to about 16 outputs

Comment: Relays would do it. Be sure to use double-pole ones and switch both connections of the speakers, since your amplifier is most likely bridge-tied. Never assume - is ground.

Comment: @Majenko: I believe that, nowadays, most audio power amplifiers are considered to be voltage sources and are constrained by their loads' impedances only insofar as the current they draw causes heating of the amplifier's output stage.

Comment: Which is why switching in more speakers in parallel would drop the impedance and cause more current to flow which would overload the output stage often causing the over-current protection to kick in. That said, I have used some class D chips which, if the speaker impedance doesn't match the output filter impedance, don't operate at all - or only for a second or two before they shut down.

Comment: If a power amplifier is designed for 100V line applications, it really ought to be tolerant of load impedance variations up to and including its output power limitations. This one claims to be, so don't worry about it.

Comment: @Majenko: 100 volts, 500 watts, 5 amperes, 0.2 ohms, all CW. Do you think that putting, say, 16 eight ohm speakers in parallel, connecting them to the amp, and then cranking it to 11 is going to shut down the amp because of the 2.5 to 1 impedance mismatch?

Comment: Without knowing the amp, who can say? It might, or it might just melt. Or it may clip, distort, and sound like shite.

Comment: 100 volts, 5 amperes implies 20 ohm load, not 0.2 ohms.

Comment: That may be true in general consumer audio applications, but does not apply to these specific long-distance distribution "constant voltage" systems (70V in the US, 100V in Europe)